# split 3gb file within aws

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are getting 3gb zipped(compressed) csv files from third party in S3 bucket.We want to split the file before `copy` command. As per snowflake standard we have to follow 200 mb.
Our current architecture is we are using python code in lambda to move that file and later process it through loader.py in EMR to envoke cluser.
We cannot download file in local.
Kindly advise what and where would be the best way to split the files.

Adding more information:
There are more than 900 columns . 2.5 hr taken by copy command till stage table and then unpivoting with merge statement takes more then 6 hrs. So splitting files will be for loading `S3` to `stage`
Below are the thoughts i have googled.

1.split it into EC2 by split command.

2.use some python code within lambda.

3.Splitting using pyspark framework

Comment: You can load files way bigger than 200mb to Snowflake - that size is only recommended for optimum performance. Is loading time a problem with 3gb already? Maybe all will work well without the extra steps.

Comment: yes Felipe, we are facing performance issue , snowflake query taking more than 8-9 hr .. we have to split the files.. kindly advice where we can split..

Comment: What kind of query is taking 9 hours? Loading 3gb of data can't take 9 hours. Please add details.

Comment: Just to add more context to the issue: is the loading happening via Snowpipe? if not you must be using a Virtual Warehouse, then check if it's overloaded and therefore your COPY is subject to queuing which could explain why it's taking so long to load. Btw 3gb zipped file doesn't seem to me "too much" to load in a reasonable time.

Comment: There are more than 900 columns . 2.5 hr taken by copy command till stage table and then unpivoting with merge statement takes more then 6 hrs. So splitting files will be for loading `S3` to `stage`. We are using xlarge. We are not using snowpipe.

Comment: Don't split the file before you load it. It's fine to load a file that large, seems like your issue is elsewhere. Does your copy command perform any transformations on the file before it loads it? (does it use a subquery?)

Comment: hi @simon its one to one load only , no transformation used. I have re-executed the code. Right now , Byte scanned 25 % , total duration 40 mnts showing.

Comment: What about the S3 bucket storage class? And which regions are S3 and Snowflake running in?